# How to draw the figure using pgf-tikz plot or Matlab?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, matlab

I want to draw the following figure using pgf-Tikz package or Matlab code (anyone):

[image]

Here I have given some names to the semi-circles  and nothing else. You can put any arbitrary names.

But I need to draw such figure in complex upper half plane which are basically semi-circles related to each other in the  above fashion.

Please suggest me at least approximate or nearby Pgf-Tikz code or Matlab.

**Edit:**

Using the following script of @SevGlav, I have got the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: a complete edition of my previous post to provide a complete and more structured example, using `\foreach` to create automated semi circles and all.
Now you just have to choose your radiuses into the `\foreach` loop, and everything is fine.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,font=\footnotesize]

    \tikzset{xmid/.style={inner sep=0pt,below}}

    \tikzset{midarrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.45 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
        postaction={decorate}}} 
    
    \draw (-5,0) -- (5,0);
        \draw (0,0) node[xmid] {\strut $O$} -- (0,5);
        \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}
            {
            \draw   (\x,0.05) --++ (0,-0.1)
                    (-\x,0.05) --++ (0,-0.1);
            }
    \foreach \r [count=\i] in {0.55,0.15,0.35,0.2}
            {
            \coordinate (a\i) at (\i-\r,0);
            \coordinate (aa\i) at (-\i+\r,0);
            
            \draw (a\i) node[xmid] {\strut $a_{\i}$} arc    (180:0:\r) node[midway] (mm\i) {}node[xmid] {\strut $b_{\i}$};  
            \draw (aa\i) node[xmid] {\strut $-a_{\i}$} arc  (0:180:\r) node[midway] (m\i) {} node[xmid] {\strut $-b_{\i}$}; 
            }
    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
        {
        \draw[midarrow] (m\i) arc (180:0:\i) node[pos=0.45,above] {$S^{'}_{\i}$};
        }
    
    \foreach \j [count=\i] in {5,6,7,8}
        {
        \node [above right] at (m\i) {$D_{\i}$};
        \node [above right] at (mm\i) {$D_{\j}$};
        }
        
\end{tikzpicture}           
\end{document}
```

[image: semicircles v2]

Comment: Thanks. But I have got different picture using your code, as given in the edited question

Comment: I don't understand why you experiment this bug. I copied my code into a new file and compiled it just to see if a double compilation would change anything, but it worked immediatly. It seems that every S and D nodes are agglomerated at (0,0). Did you try to copy/paste it again?

Comment: Your code running nicely but the output figure is same. May be my Latex editor is old version

Answer (score 2):

You can try use [IPE](http://ipe.otfried.org/), an awesome tool for who wants to draw things like that without use Tikz.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am unable to use the package. How to put horizontal and vertical lines and how to put semi-circles  and how to put text above the semi-circles ?

Comment: It's not a package, i'ts a program like Geogebra, you can draw using the optins it givest to you. All the installation and manual you can find here: http://ipe.otfried.org/. If you want another manual: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335813672_IPE_Tutorial_for_version_7212_The_Extensible_Drawing_Editor_by_Otfried_Cheong

Comment: Thanks. I feel easy to use Geogebra which you suggested. Thanks for it. Is there any video tutorial to use `IPE`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I learned from the manual that I sent as a link here and gradually, researching a lot and always. It's a battle, but it's worth it.

Comment: I just want to know regarding IPE.  Do we have to select a box area and then plot everything within that box  ?

Comment: Not necessarily. I draw the axes, click on some corner of the screen to deselect them, draw a function and click again on some corner to deselect them and so on. In the end, I select everything, use the tool that has the shortcut "E", to stretch, hold the Shift and increase the size of everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try. I may ask for further

Answer (score 2):

Making all the semi-circles in a single loop. A scale factor has been included. With higher values for the scale factor, it is possible to increase the font size used for the point names along the x axis, or to prevent rotation.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\rArray{0.5, 0.18, 0.42, 0.3}  %% semi-circles radius

\def\mScale{1.4}  %%  To adjust the sizes

\draw[-latex] (-5*\mScale,0) -- (5*\mScale,0) node[below] {$\sigma$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,5*\mScale) node[right] {$j \omega$};
\node at (0,-0.5) {$0$};
\foreach \i [count=\c] in \rArray{
    \draw[thick] (\mScale*\c-\mScale*\i,0) node[rotate=90, left] {\footnotesize $a_{\c}$} arc (180:0:\i*\mScale) node[rotate=90, left] {\footnotesize $b_{\c}$};
    \draw[thick] (-\mScale*\c+\mScale*\i,0) node[rotate=90, left] {\footnotesize $-a_{\c}$} arc (0:180:\i*\mScale) node[rotate=90, left] {\footnotesize $-b_{\c}$};
    \draw[thick] (-\c*\mScale, \i*\mScale) arc (180:0:\c*\mScale);
    \node at (\c*\mScale-0.9*\mScale*\i, \mScale*\i+0.2) {\footnotesize $D_\c$};
    \node at (-\c*\mScale+0.9*\mScale*\i, \mScale*\i+0.2) {\footnotesize $D_\c$};
    \draw (0,0) ++(0,\i*\mScale) ++(100:\c*\mScale) node [above] {$S_{\c}'$};
    \draw[thick,-latex] (0,0) ++(0,\i*\mScale) ++(100:\c*\mScale)  arc (100:99:\c*\mScale);
    \draw (\c*\mScale, -0.07) --+(0,0.14);
    \draw (-\c*\mScale, -0.07) --+(0,0.14);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your code worked fine. But can you change  the style of   the footnotes a_i, b_i below the horizontal axis just like the above picture in the previous answer by @SevGlav

Comment: Also can you explain what the last two lines `\draw (\c*\mScale, -0.07) --+(0,0.14);
  \draw (-\c*\mScale, -0.07) --+(0,0.14);` of code means for ?

Comment: Just change `node[rotate=90, left] {\footnotesize $b_{\c}$}` by `node[below] {\footnotesize $b_{\c}$}` to avoid this rotation.

Comment: The last two lines draw marks on the x axis. This solution assumes that the centers of the lower semi-circles are equally spaced from each other. If the centers of the semi-circles assume arbitrary and symmetrical positions, you must create another array with the positions of these centers, and adjust the code to take this feature into account.

Answer (score 1):

This solution allows to place the centers of the semi circles in arbitrary, but symmetrical positions.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\rArray{{0.4, 0.18, 0.42, 0.2}}  %% semi-circles radius
\def\cArray{{0.6,2,3,3.8}}  %% semi-circles centers

\def\mScale{2}  %%  To adjust the sizes


\pgfmathsetmacro\ax{\mScale*\rArray[3] +\mScale*\cArray[3] +0.5}
\draw[-latex] (-\ax,0) -- (\ax,0) node[below] {$\sigma$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,\ax) node[right] {$j \omega$};
\node at (0,-0.5) {$0$};
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rs{\mScale*\rArray[\x]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cs{\mScale*\cArray[\x]}
    \draw[thick] (\cs-\rs, 0) node[below] {\footnotesize $a_{\x}$} arc (180:0:\rs) node[below] {\footnotesize $b_{\x}$};
    \draw[thick] (-\cs+\rs, 0) node[below] {\footnotesize $-a_{\x}$} arc (0:180:\rs) node[below] {\footnotesize $-b_{\x}$};
    \draw[thick] (-\cs, \rs) arc (180:0:\cs);
    \node at (\cs-0.75*\rs, \rs+0.2) {\footnotesize $D_\x$};
    \node at (-\cs+0.75*\rs, \rs+0.2) {\footnotesize $D_\x$};
    
    \draw (0,0) ++(0,\rs) ++(110:\cs) node [above] {$S_{\x}'$};
    \draw[thick,-latex] (0,0) ++(0,\rs) ++(110:\cs)  arc (110:109:\cs);
    \draw (\cs, -0.07) --+(0,0.14);
    \draw (-\cs, -0.07) --+(0,0.14);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]